# How to say in a positive, joke manner "you're a boring person" using a noun

Tags: single-word-request

What is German word for "a boring person" but in positive context, so there is no offence? Russian equivalent is "зануда" (if this can help).

I can say it in simple phrase "Du bist langweilig", but it looks too primitive.

Comment: Isn't this always rather negative, still? I think this usually not conveyed by another word, but rather by stress and irony, e.g. "Na du bist ja ein richtiger Abenteurer!". But this is very colloquial and really depends on the situation.

Comment: @chaero Yes, I agree with this, it is more about intonation, than the sentence itself. But could you than just suggest a correct translation? With the lowest level of offence in the word :D

Comment: It doesn't matter which word you choose; every word will be considered negatively if you direct that to a person. The only way to swap meaning is - as @chaero said - to make it irony. - However, which word is appropriate depends on context. General words could be *fad* or *öde* but even those won't fit in every context.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for “[Spießer](http://www.dict.cc/?s=spießer)” or even better “[Spielverderber](http://www.dict.cc/?s=spielverderber)”. You can use “Langweiler”, too. Also, `dict.cc` is great. Check “[зануда](http://deru.dict.cc/?s=зануда)”. By the way, I love “Fadian”.

Comment: @K.Stm. Thanks a lot! Decided to use Spielverderber. I was called a nerd by one person for playing Minecraft, so I'll call him Spielverderber in return :D

Comment: @K.Stm. Could you write this as an answer. So we can upvote and Anestuk can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making an answer out of the comment:

Maybe you are looking for “[Spießer](http://www.dict.cc/?s=spie%C3%9Fer)” or even better “[Spielverderber](http://www.dict.cc/?s=spielverderber)”. You can use “Langweiler”, too. Also, `dict.cc` is great. Check “[зануда](http://deru.dict.cc/?s=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0)”. By the way, I love “Fadian”.

Comment: Ein Spielverderber muss kein Langweiler sein, und viele Langweiler sind keine Spielverderber.

Answer (score 0):

We would say in Yiddish (taking our cue from the Russian) "du bist a nudnik". (But I don't know how that's not a put-down in any language.)

Comment: But a nudnik is also a "pain" (Nervensäge). Perhaps the Asker should wrap his insult (for an insult it is) in a colorful package to soften the blow… If you can get a chuckle out of them, that's half the battle won already… I would type more to continue our exciting conversation but I feel my head grow heavy and droop towards the keybgozt5867ghhvngj